# CQL Error InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table employess"

Tags: cassandra, cql

Very much new to CQL (Cassendra) . I get this error when inserting records,

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table
>   employess"

These are the commands issued, Am i missing anything . (I am trying this Cassendra CQL shell)

```
CREATE KEYSPACE people WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;

USE people;
CREATE Table employees(id uuid,name varchar,PRIMARY KEY(id, email));


cqlsh:people> insert into employess (id,name,email) values (now(),'Jon Don','jd@gmail.com');
```

Answer (score 21):

You have misspelled your table: it's `employees`, not `employess`.

Comment: Such a shame Really Sorry !

Comment: @FabTrex, if this is right, do mark it as answered :)